# How to skip a line using curses in Python?

Tags: python, terminal, curses

I'm trying to find how to skip a line with curses. I've tried
`screen.addchr('\n')` and `screen.addstr("\n")` but it didn't work. How can I do that ?

Comment: oh it was about *curses*. Now that actually makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [`screen.addch`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.addch) or [`screen.addstr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.addstr) in curses to pass a newline, it clears the remainder of the line.  Instead, if you want to move *down* a line, you should get the current position using [`screen.getyx`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.getyx) and use [`screen.move`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.move) to move to the next line (by adding `1` to the y-value).

Further reading:

- [*Adding characters*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html) (curs_addch(3x)
- [**`getyx`**,  **`getparyx`**,  **`getbegyx`**,  **`getmaxyx`** - *get curses cursor
     and window coordinates*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getyx.3x.html)